# XML Download via ResponseEntity not working in IE

Tags: java, xml, spring, httpresponse

I have a webapp that enables a user to download an XML file. I use Spring's Response entity to return the generated file.

It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, directly prompts the user to save the file. Also works when you right click and "download as". However on IE, it opens the XML in the browser. Yet I cant download the file. First of all it completly ignores my filename so i get a prompt to download 'baseURL/download?id=xx' and it prompts a .html download and doesnt even manage to download it : 'File could not be downloaded'.

This is what my method looks like. And a few things i tried in comments...

```
@RequestMapping
public ResponseEntity<Classification> handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Classification xmlToDownload = null;

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

//      responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

//      responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Classification.xml\" ");
//      responseHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", "Classification.xml");

    responseHeaders.setCacheControl("public");
    responseHeaders.setPragma("public");


        xmlToDownload = classificationsService.getClassificationById(Long.valueOf(classificationId));
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Classification>(xmlToDownload, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Something wrong in my headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I never got it to work on IE this way...
I tried saving the file to the disk, then downloading it in the response outputstream. Which worked (on IE too)
But i didn't like that, in case multiple users asked for the file concurrently... Since it was generated each time someone needed it.

Instead I used a JAXB marshall method that took my response outpustream as parameter and directly wrote the XML in there.

So here's what it looks like in the end:

```
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Classification.xml\"");

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Classification.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    m.marshal(xmlToDownload, response.getOutputStream());
```

So I basically had to do everything differently just for IE....